# Bone not listed in vertex group

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I rigged my character, but for some reason, only the foot bones are not listed in the vertex group. When I pose the character, the foot bones are influenced by other bones, but nothing happens when I rotate the foot bones itself. I have tried re-rigging the character with empty weight, but it still doesn't work.
Any help would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YDd-b5xkl_n_6XvpXGFZ7Xj_kFzhRVXz/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've disabled the *Deform* option of these bones, so enable it (and disable it for the bones that are not supposed to deform, like the IK target or pole target bones):

[image]

Then parent again, or if you want to preserve your previous settings, just select the armature, shift select the mesh, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select the bone(s) you want (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to select a bone, <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select more than one), and *Weights > Assign Automatic From Bones* (here it's better to recalculate for the shins as well as for the moment they also control the feet):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :) It worked!